# how to select all the cells in this maatwebsite laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel, maatwebsite-excel

I am trying to format my cells to align center. In the documentation There is example to select a specific cell and cell range only. how do i format the entire sheet to have everything center aligned?

```
$sheet->cells('A1:A5', function($cells) {

// manipulate the range of cells

});
```

I want to select all cells instead of a range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the layout of the entire excel sheet using the following code

```
 Excel::create('Filename', function($excel) {
 $excel->getDefaultStyle()
    ->getAlignment()
    ->setHorizontal(\PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER)
});
```

This will center all cells horizontally. To center them vertically, add

```
Excel::create('Filename', function($excel) {
$excel->getDefaultStyle()
    ->getAlignment()
    ->setVertical(\PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, i use this way to set all text to be centered.

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ShouldAutoSize;

class UsersExport implements FromCollection, WithHeadings, ShouldAutoSize, WithStyles
{

  public function styles(Worksheet $sheet)
  {
      $sheet->getStyle($sheet->calculateWorksheetDimension())
            ->getAlignment()
            ->setHorizontal(Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER)
            ->setVertical(Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);
  }
}
```

for other details maybe you can read on this page
https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/column-formatting.html

I hope this helps :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).